# Does 'Chatter in Apex' aka Chatter Connect API support Bulkified insert operations?

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

I want to add Chatter feeds from Trigger and obviously I am going to implement this as Bulkified.

I have data in the following format.

```
Public Class ChatterFeedInfo
{
    public Id usermentionId {get;set;} // user records to which chatter feed will be @mentioned [@John Doe]
    public Id recordId {get;set;} // parent record id
    public String body {get;set;} // feed body
    public Id chatterGroupId {get;set;} // if not null  post this feed to Chatter Group
}
```

I get `List<ChatterFeedInfo> chatterFeeds` in my trigger but not sure how to implement this with 'Chatter in Apex'.

Please suggest.

Comment: I would imagine not - ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem takes a String or a FeedItem, not a list. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_ChatterFeedsClass.htm

Comment: if its true then its really sad and bad news :(, SFDC suggests that code should be bulkified but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can bulk insert to FeedItem directly in Apex, but unfortunately you cannot perform an @mention this way.  Also, techtrekker is right about using the Connect API, it doesn't support multiple inserts at once.

Tell us a little about your implementation.  You might be able to do this from another perspective.  You mentioned doing this from a trigger.  Is the trigger being fired from insert/update from custom code (i.e. VF/apex) or some other mechanism?

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was about.  Only reason I didn't ask the question in a comment was because at the time I had no comment ability.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue.

Similar to what you are doing, I have a pod data class to wrap `Feed Items` I want to post. I also created a shadow object, e.g. `Chatter_Feed_Info__c`.

In my trigger, I check how many DML statements remain. If I cannot insert all my `Feed Items` one at a time under the limit, I bulk create the shadow objects instead. Then I call a batch that posts the shadow Feed Items to Chatter 150 at a time.

**Disclaimer: I haven't gotten to testing yet.**