# @Mention with apex code

Tags: apex, chatter

In this post i want mention the user.
I'm using the connect apex chatter.

I'don't know how mention the user with u.id,and now i'm getting an error:

> FATAL_ERROR System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Please can you take a look to my code?

Thank you in advance.

```
    Global class RandomPilot implements Schedulable{

        //FOR TEST METHOD
        public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';

        Global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
        {
            // SEARCH BY STATIC RESOURCE NAME
            // Post a feed item that has an @-mention.
            String communityId = null;

            for(User u:lstu)
            {
                // CREATE A FEED_ITEM_TEXT
                String feedItemText= 'Happy Birthday!';

                ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = FeedBodyParser.convertToFeedItemInput(feedItemText);

                // POST FILE_FEED_ITEM
                ConnectApi.NewFileAttachmentInput fileIn = new 
                 ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(communityId,ConnectApi.FeedType.Record,fgroup.id, feedItemInput, feedBinary);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I posted that recipe when Connect in Apex was not available, however its now available and a lot easier to do. http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/getting-started-with-connect-in-apex.html

Comment: This code has callout(invoked method mention()) in for loop, which is more likely to hit limits, even new Chatter connect API is also not bulkified, basically there is no scalable way to implement chatter mention in bulkified manner. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/does-chatter-in-apex-aka-chatter-connect-api-support-bulkified-insert-operatio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the future context, the `UserInfo.getSessionId()` evaluates to null.

You'd need to pass in the sessionId from the method invocation to future.

So,

```
public static void mention(string uid,string RecordId, String sessionId){
```

And whilst invoking it, pass in the Session Id

```
mention(u.id,post.id, mention(u.id,post.id,UserInfo.getSessionId() );
```

I'd still urge you to implement with [Connect in Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm) rather than this Chatter REST API Callout.

**How to mention with Connect**

Copy the FeedBodyParser Utility Class from
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/connect-in-apex-pilot

Then to post a mention simply use

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = FeedBodyParser.convertToFeedItemInput('Hello @[Ritesh Aswaney](user:005i0000000nEVV)');      
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me', feedItemInput, null);
```

(You're going to end up creating two posts, one via your insert and one via the REST API - whereas I'd imagine you intend creating just the one)

Comment: Thank you very much!before choosing of use callouts I tried connect but it seemed complicated.
Can you tell me which steps i need to do to implement the solution with  Connect?1)i have created the helper classes:FeedFormatter,CommentInfo. which is in the example the code that show how create a post with all informations like body,createdby?...i'm using this example http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/getting-started-with-connect-in-apex.html
Thanks again,you are very kind.

Comment: @Enry edited my answer to include how to mention with Connect.

Comment: Thank you very much! i am going to try your solution.If i will have any problems i will let you know.Thanks for the support :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: caution there is no bulkified way to implement chatter mention, if you implement this in for loop with lots of records, you are likely to hit limits - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12484/does-chatter-in-apex-aka-chatter-connect-api-support-bulkified-insert-operatio

Comment: I believe the Chatter API has a limit of 200 req/ user / hour (2000 in Summer 13?, but some requests are more expensive than others).

Comment: techtekker please can you help me again, i have problems with the new implementation.I've updated my question.Thank you

Comment: @Enry Does it give you a line number where the exception occurs ? (Prolly best starting a new question, else this gets a tad confusing :) )

Comment: Thank you very much! my class works fine!! Now i have a problem with the test class. Please can you help me again? new question at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12855/test-class-for-connectapi-chatter-post

Comment: In addition, we've provided a helper Apex class that you can use to make it easier to post mentions. You can get it from github (https://github.com/alouie-sfdc/ConnectApiHelper), and there's a blog post about it too (http://www.bridgefarmconsulting.com/blog/new-helper-classes-for-working-with-the-connectapi/).